# What is the difference between sample weight and class weight options in scikit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have class imbalance problem and want to solve this using cost sensitive learning.

1. under sample and over sample
2. give weights to class to use a modified loss function

**Question**

Scikit learn has 2 options called class weights and sample weights. Is sample weight actually doing option 2) and class weight options 1). Is option 2) the the recommended way of handling class imbalance.

Comment: I think that this largely depends upon the problem. Can you provide some more information about how imbalanced your data is, and perhaps what you've already tried?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's similar concepts, but with sample_weights you can force estimator to pay more attention on some samples, and with class_weights you can force estimator to learn with attention to some particular class. sample_weight=0 or class_weight=0 basically means that estimator doesn't need to take into consideration such samples/classes in learning process at all. Thus classifier (for example) will never predict some class if class_weight = 0 for this class. If some sample_weight/class_weight bigger than sample_weight/class_weight on other samples/classes - estimator will try to minimize error on that samples/classes in the first place. You can use user-defined sample_weights and class_weights simultaneously.

If you want to undersample/oversample your training set with simple cloning/removing - this will be equal to increasing/decreasing of corresponding sample_weights/class_weights.

In more complex cases you can also try artificially generate samples, with  techniques like [SMOTE](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/project/jair/pub/volume16/chawla02a-html/chawla2002.html).

Comment: Just to clarify, it seems that "/" means "slash" in this answer and not "division". Good explanation overall.

Comment: @DataMan, yes, this is true. I agree that sample_weight/class_weight=0 looks weird.

Comment: @IbraimGaniev Let's say I have a dataset, with 100k samples. 99% are 0, and 1% are 1. How would I specify my sample weights for this data? Would it be a ratio of 1:100 or something else? `clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)[source]` and scikit docs says: `Per-sample weights. Rescale C per sample. Higher weights force the classifier to put more emphasis on these points.` I don't understand what to physically write as values in this code :`sameple_weight = {0:.01, 1:.90}` or would it have to be a vector? If so how?

Comment: A word of caution with respect to SMOTE: You cannot reliably generate samples if you have too small samples, or if the features overlap.

Answer (score 8):

`sample_weight` and `class_weight` have a similar function, that is to make your estimator pay more attention to some samples.

**Actual sample weights will be `sample_weight * weights from class_weight`.**

This serves the same purpose as under/oversampling but the behavior is likely to be different: say you have an algorithm that randomly picks samples (like in random forests), it matters whether you oversampled or not.

To sum it up:
`class_weight` and `sample_weight` both do 2), option 2) is *one way* to handle class imbalance. I don't know of an universally recommended way, I would try 1), 2) and 1) + 2) on your specific problem to see what works best.

Comment: @Idrier  Let's say I have a dataset, with 100k samples. 99% are 0, and 1% are 1. How would I specify my sample weights for this data? Would it be a ratio of 1:100 or something else? `clf.fit(X, y, sample_weight=None)[source]` and scikit docs says: `Per-sample weights. Rescale C per sample. Higher weights force the classifier to put more emphasis on these points.` I don't understand what to physically write as values in this code :`sameple_weight = {0:.01, 1:.90}` or would it have to be a vector? If so how?

Comment: @Chuck I'm also confused on the same thing as you are. I'm interested to know the exact formulae that are applied to both Sample weight and Class weight calculation, Idirer gave good example for a formulae, but I'm also looking for a practical example like your question.

Answer (score 0):

assume you have 5 samples of which the first two are of class A and the last three of class B. to "achieve balance" you can then assign weights either to the two classes (e.g. `class_weight=[0.6, 0.4]`) or to the five samples (e.g. `sample_weight=[0.25, 0.25, 0.167, 0.167, 0.167]`). `sample_weight` thus allows a more fine-grained weighting at the level of samples instead of classes.

if you use both weightings then the actual weight of a sample will be the product of its `sample_weight` with the `class_weight` of its class, and you don't usually want that. also, some will say that assigning weights to samples in order to balance classes is conceptually awkward (in particular in multilabel classification where the same sample can belong to both a very frequent and a sparsely populated class, so what sample weight would you assign?) or at least unnecessarily complicated. so you would usually deal with imbalanced classes via `class_weight` and only use sample_weight "on top" if you want to additionally change individual weights of specific samples, e.g. in order to "zero" specific samples.

as far as i know, not all functions or metrics in `sklearn` offer both arguments. if you have a binary classifier and really need to balance classes via `sample_weight` because the metric doesn't accept `class_weight` (not sure if this scenario exists at all, but just in case...) then you can get sample weights for balanced classes using `sample_weights = compute_sample_weight(class_weight='balanced', y=y_true)` with `compute_sample_weight` from `sklearn.utils.class_weight`.