# How can correct sample_weight in sklearn.naive_bayes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm implementing `Naive Bayes` by `sklearn` with imbalanced data.
My data has more than 16k records and 6 output categories.

I tried to fit the model with the `sample_weight` calculated by `sklearn.utils.class_weight`

The `sample_weight` received something like:

sample_weight = [11.77540107  1.82284768  0.64688602  2.47138047  0.38577435  1.21389195]

```py
import numpy as np

data_set = np.loadtxt("./data/_vector21.csv", delimiter=",")

inp_vec = data_set[:, 1:22]
out_vec = data_set[:, 22:]
#
# # Split dataset into training set and test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inp_vec, out_vec, test_size=0.2)    # 80% training and 20% test
#
# class weight
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
output_vec_categorical = to_categorical(y_train)
from sklearn.utils import class_weight
y_ints = [y.argmax() for y in output_vec_categorical]
c_w = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(y_ints), y_ints)
cw = {}
for i in set(y_ints):
    cw[i] = c_w[i]

# Create a Gaussian Classifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import *
model = GaussianNB()

# Train the model using the training sets
print(c_w)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, c_w)

# Predict the response for test dataset
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

# Import scikit-learn metrics module for accuracy calculation
from sklearn import metrics

# Model Accuracy, how often is the classifier correct?
print("\nClassification Report: \n", (metrics.classification_report(y_test, y_pred)))
print("\nAccuracy: %.3f%%" % (metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)*100))
```

I got this message:
`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [13212, 6]`

Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong and how can fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sample_weight` and `class_weight` are two different things.

As their name suggests:

- `sample_weight` is to be applied to individual samples (rows in your data). So the length of `sample_weight` must match the number of samples in your `X`.
- `class_weight` is to make the classifier give more importance and attention to the classes. So the length of `class_weight` must match the number of classes in your targets.

You are calculating `class_weight` and not `sample_weight` by using the `sklearn.utils.class_weight`, but then try to pass it to the `sample_weight`. Hence the dimension mismatch error.

Please see the following questions for more understanding of how these two weights interact internally:

- [What is the difference between sample weight and class weight options in scikit learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32492550/what-is-the-difference-between-sample-weight-and-class-weight-options-in-scikit)
- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244630/difference-between-sample-weight-and-class-weight-randomforest-classifier

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is very clear. I changed from `compute_class_weight` to `compute_sample_weight`

Answer (score 2):

This way I was able to calculate the weights to deal with class imbalance.

```py
from sklearn.utils import class_weight

sample = class_weight.compute_sample_weight('balanced', y_train)

#Classifier Naive Bayes
naive = naive_bayes.MultinomialNB()
naive.fit(X_train,y_train, sample_weight=sample)
predictions_NB = naive.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: how can I visualize what Naive Bayes do something with sample_with under the hood when its loss function is not Cross Entropy?